# bundle exception in eclipse upgrade 4.5.2 to 4.10

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I upgraded my eclipse RCP based application from 4.5.2 to 4.10. I setup target platform and pointed it to new eclipse plugin directory as well.
And when I try to launch the application, it shows below errors.
Can somebody suggest any check list which I should follow for eclipse based applications upgrade and what am I missing here?

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2019-05-30 06:33:32.513
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
>   !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:451)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1763)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1725)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1656)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:233)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:343)
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2019-05-30 06:33:32.513
>   !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: javax.inject; bundle-version="1.0.0"; visibility:="reexport"; resolution:="optional"
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-05-30 06:33:32.529
>   !MESSAGE Application error
>   !STACK 1
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1474)

Answer (score 0):

Your log suggests problems with the `javax.inject` and `org.eclipse.core.jobs` plug-ins.

In the 'Run > Run Configurations...' dialog find your RCP in the 'Eclipse Application' section.

Use the 'Add Required Plug-ins' button to add all plug-ins your RCP uses. This will change between releases.

Use the 'Validate Plug-ins' button to validate that the selected plug-ins set is reasonable.